# Raphael: mouseout not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, svg, mouseevent, raphael, mouseout

I noticed that in IE11 that mouseout isn't activating my desired functionality. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Does anyone know why this is and what the solution could be?

```
    wheel[segment].mouseout( myHoverOut.bind(null, segment) )
    icon[segment].mouseout( myHoverOut.bind(null, segment) )
```

Full Code: https://jsfiddle.net/8aue977o/

Working Wheel: (scroll to wheel) https://www.uk-cpi.com/services/innovation-integrator

Answer (score 0):

Could use Pure JS, It's very simple : http://jsfiddle.net/qHfJD/76/

```
<script>

var myDiv = document.getElementById('foo');

myDiv.onmouseout = function() { 
alert('left');
}

</script>
```